# Who is setting cookie in Request object on call to server controller

Tags: c#, security

I have a code from Github (aspnet-core-3-signup-verification-api). On the authentication in the controller the `refreshToken` is set correctly like below:

```
 Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
```

But then when the refresh token function is called by the client the following server code :

```
var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];
```

... returns null in `refreshToken`. I am using Chrome browser.
Who is responsible from setting the `refreshToken` cookie in Request object (I thought it was browser - which in my case is Chrome)

Comment: c# code isn't using Chrome.  The cookies are stored in the user store (in temp space) and is used by any browser or application like c#.  The cookie refresh is sent to server, server returns updated cookie, than cookie is taken from response and placed in the user stores.

Comment: Isn't that also true:  The cookie is generated on the server, server returns cookie to client, than cookie is taken from response and placed in the Request in the next call to server. Otherwise the code would not be working

Comment: It is handled in a library in c#.  You said Chrome.

Comment: So in the code ` var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];` is not retrieved from the HTTP header ?

Comment: Request is what is sent from client to server.  Response is what comes from server to client.  The cookies refresh is sent in request header and the response contains the update cookie in the header.

Comment: That is correct. So I am right in saying that the cookie header is not set on the way from client to the server - as I am getting null from `Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];`

Comment: When you create a new request the header doesn't exist.   So you are reading a null header.  You need to add the header to the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248258/discussion-between-user19564787-and-jdweng).